# Extract string between newline and variable data in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

As part of a load test, I've a file with a generated list of requests. The format is below, in that, the payload is in between two newline characters; the GET indicating the start of a new request. I would like to extract only the payload.

```
Connection: false
Content-Length: 25

foo=bar1&foo2=bar2

GET http://localhost:1080/dasistgut
```

I have tried several combinations without success:

```
grep -zoP "(?<=(\n)).*(?<=(\GET))"  sample.txt
grep -zoP "(?<=(\n)).*(?<=(\n))"  sample.txt
grep -zoP "(?<=(\n)).*(?<=\n)"  sample.txt
```

Expected output: `foo=bar1&foo2=bar2`

Comment: `grep` processes one line at a time, you can't use it to match across multiple lines.

Comment: It would help if you edit your question to show the result you expect.

Comment: To OP: Are you trying to find something in between two **blank** lines?

Comment: It's still not clear what output you want.  Do you want exactly one line of output, or do you want everything between "Content-Length" and "GET" (including 2 blank lines).  What do you want if there are multiple non-blank lines of payload? Do you want the final blank line in your output?

Comment: Expected output: foo=bar1&foo2=bar2 as mentioned in the description. Apologies as I thought I had made it clear that I only want the payload ie. the text/bodyString that is between the Content-Length and GET.

Comment: To properly implement the HTTP protocol, you should read the `Content-length`, skip over the blank line, then read that many bytes to get the payload.

Comment: And you also need to implement *chunked encoding*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `gnu grep`:

```
var=$(grep -zoP '.+(?=\R{2}GET )' file)
```

```
echo "$var"
foo=bar1&foo2=bar2
```

Lookahead assertion `(?=\R{2}GET )` makes sure that input has exact 2 newlines (`\R`) followed by `"GET "` ahead of current position.

---

**Alternative** `awk` based solution:

```
awk '!NF{++n; next} n && /^GET /{print p} {p=$0; n=0}' file
```

```
foo=bar1&foo2=bar2
```

Comment: The first solution works against the sample I provided in the description. Although I did mention it is part of a file that has a few thousand such request entries for which the output is blank. The awk alternative works for me although it is a bit slow over the iteration. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` to match a blank line, get the next line and print it, then skip the next line (which should always be blank).

```
awk '/^$/ { getline; print; getline; }' sample.text
```

Comment: It works against the sample I provided in the description. Although I did mention that it is part of a file that has a few thousand such request entries but it results in a blank output.

Comment: @LP This only returns the first payload in the file. If there are thousands of such requests, you want all of them printed?

Comment: I've updated the answer to repeat it instead of exiting.